# multi-threaded rospy.get_param() crashes: CannotSendRequest and ResponseNotReady

Tags: ros, rospy, multi-thread, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I work with the sushi repository from the [ICRA Mobile Manipulation Challenge](https://kforge.ros.org/Sushi/trac/wiki).
When instantiating the *ArmMover* I get "CannotSendRequest" and "ResponseNotReady" exceptions. The *ArmMover* class creates multiple *ArmMoverWorker*, which run their own threads. The reason for the crash seems to be **requests to the parameter server from multiple threads**.

Can the parameter server process multiple requests from different threads running on the same node?

As a workaround I moved the parameter requests into the constructor of the *ArmMoverWorker* (before the thread is started) and then it works fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36822/multi-threaded-rospy.get_param()-crashes:-cannotsendrequest-and-responsenotready/) by [Andy](https://answers.ros.org/users/968/andy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-06-21**:
Can anyone else using the Sushi code verify this? Running move_arms_to_side.py with simulation causes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me this looks like a bug in rospy. You should probably file a ticket at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0